# Paste range of cells to first empty row and empty column

Tags: excel, vba

What im trying to achieve is to copy 3 first cells from sheet "Arkusz1" and paste it sheet "Arkusz2" to first empty column and first empty row in that column. After this the process reapeats. I have code wich paste it to first empty row in column A but it doesnt work properly as described above. I will apreciate any help.

```
Skok = Sheets("Arkusz3").Range("B1").Value
ActiveCellRow = ActiveCell.Row
Dim NextRow As Range
Set NextRow = Range(A + 1 & Sheets("Arkusz2").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 0)
Worksheets("Arkusz1").Activate
Sheets("Arkusz1").Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(Skok, 0).Activate
Range("A1", ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Arkusz2").Activate
NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set NextRow = Nothing
```

Comment: Will A1, A2, A3 on pg1 always go to A1, A2, A3 on pg2 everytime? Or the second time around will A1, A2, A3 on pg1 need to go to A4, A5, A6 on pg 2?

Comment: The second time it should go down by value in sheet "Arkusz3" cell B1. Example if this cell contains 3 it should next time go to A4, A5, A6.

Answer (score 1):

In this example I am taking A1, A2, A3 from sheet 1, and copying it to sheet 2. Then it will go down to the next set per iterate(A4, A5, A6 and so on). However, I'm not fully sure what you are expecting so this should be a good start.

```
Dim s1a1 As String, s1a2 As String, s1a3 As String
Dim s2a1 As Long, s2a2 As Long, s2a3 As Long
Dim i As Integer

s2a1 = 1
s2a2 = 2
s2a3 = 3

For i = 1 To 6


s1a1 = Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(1, "A")
s1a2 = Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(2, "A")
s1a3 = Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(3, "A")

Worksheets("Arkusz2").Range("A" & s2a1) = s1a1
Worksheets("Arkusz2").Range("A" & s2a2) = s1a2
Worksheets("Arkusz2").Range("A" & s2a3) = s1a3

s2a1 = s2a1 + 3
s2a2 = s2a2 + 3
s2a3 = s2a3 + 3

Next i
```

Comment: @ScottCraner Will Activate ever be faster than referencing directly in any situations?

Comment: No, every time that vba must reference the worksheet it will slow down.  That is why loading a range of cells into an array and iterating through the array is quicker than iterating through the cells directly.  With arrays you only make the crossing once instead of one per the number of cells in the range.  To speed up code in vba limit the number of time the worksheet is referenced, do as much as possible in memory and not on the sheet. There are times that Activate and Select can not be avoided but they are very very few.